# How to break the 2048bit BigInteger into words with a fixed number of 64 bits?

Tags: java, biginteger, xor

I have a key that contain 2048 bit BigInteger number.
I want to break it into words with a fixed number of 64 bits, and then computes the exclusive OR of all those words;
does anyone can help me to implement this by java?
this is my method that must be implemented:

```
public static BigInteger parityWordChecksum(BigInteger key) {
//result is a 64 bit integer
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: i don't have any code,i just want to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LongBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(myBigInteger.toByteArray()).asLongBuffer();
long xor = 0;
while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
  xor ^= buffer.get();
}
return BigInteger.valueOf(xor);
```

Comment: Hi louis , thank you.do u sure break it into 64 bit words?!

Comment: That's the `asLongBuffer` part; longs have 64 bits.

Comment: very good.but i want biginteger output.how do i cast it into biginteger?

Comment: `BigInteger.valueOf(xor)` will do the job.